# Observable on UI using async

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, observable, angularfire2

I have below code

```
 this.dlist$ = this.dbCollectionService.datalists .snapshotChanges().map(
      items => {
        return items.map(a => {
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          return { id,...data}
        })
      }
    );
```

> datalists  is firestore collection

it is correctly giving data, I check through console.

Below is UI part

```
 <div >
              <p>Or choose from an existing one</p>
              <ul class="list">
                <li *ngFor="let item of dlist | async;  let i=index">
                      <span>item.name</span>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </div>
```

**

list is not binding.

**UPdate**

I find the issue it was $ missing at the end

Please help

Comment: Its `async` not `asyc`

Comment: It was typo mistake, any way I find the issue it was $ missing at the end

Comment: And you're sure payload.doc exists on 'a'?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some {{ }} and the keyword should be async.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of dlist | async;  let i=index">
   <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: It was typo mistake, any way I find the issue it was $ missing at the end

Comment: you also forgot to interpolate the string though when rendering the list items using {{ }}

Comment: I was just printing the object only to check its async working or not. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing curly braces, and the pipe is `async` not `asyc`.

Comment: It was typo mistake, any way I find the issue it was $ missing at the end

Answer (score 0):

Its `async` and interpolation of the data is not done

```
<li *ngFor="let item of dlist | async;  let i=index">
   <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: It was typo mistake, any way I find the issue it was $ missing at the end